# Understanding print matrix in clockwise spiral in Python

Tags: python, arrays, 2d-vector

I found this exercise to study matrices or 2d vectors in Python (I'm beginner)

```
'''
start row index - k 
end row index - m
start column index - l
end column index - n
iterator - i 
array or list - a
'''
# Python3 program to print  
# given matrix in spiral form 
def spiralPrint(m, n, a) : 
    k = 0; l = 0

    ''' k - starting row index 
        m - ending row index 
        l - starting column index 
        n - ending column index 
        i - iterator '''


    while (k < m and l < n) : 

        # Print the first row from 
        # the remaining rows  
        for i in range(l, n) : 
            print(a[k][i], end = " ") 

        k += 1

        # Print the last column from 
        # the remaining columns  
        for i in range(k, m) : 
            print(a[i][n - 1], end = " ") 

        n -= 1

        # Print the last row from 
        # the remaining rows  
        if ( k < m) : 

            for i in range(n - 1, (l - 1), -1) : 
                print(a[m - 1][i], end = " ") 

            m -= 1

        # Print the first column from 
        # the remaining columns  
        if (l < n) : 
            for i in range(m - 1, k - 1, -1) : 
                print(a[i][l], end = " ") 

            l += 1


a =[[1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7,8,9,10],
    [11,12,13,14,15],
    [16,17,18,19,20]]
R = 4
C = 5

spiralPrint(R,C,a)
```

I wanted to understand the logic behind it, I mean why they were used 4 loops  to iterate and why they assigned indices as rows and columns?
Also, how does the function know exactly that at the end of the element it has to go under the second list and go around?

Answer (score 0):

There are four for-loops, one for each side of the spiral.
Each iteration of the while-loop writes out one *ring* of the matrix. `k` and `m` control how much of each side column needs to be printed. `k` starts at `0` and `m` at the height of the matrix. Each time a top row is printed,  `k` gets incremented by 1, so the subsequent columns to be printed start one row lower. Each time a bottom row is printed,  `m` gets decremented by 1, so the subsequent columns to be printed stop one row higher.

Similarly, `l` and `n` control how much of each row needs to be printed, and get adjusted every time a column is printed.

Everything is easier to follow if you draw the matrix on a sheet of paper and write out `k`, `m`, `l` and `n` while you mark the parts that are being printed.

The exercise is a good illustration of how ranges work in Python.

Comment: Was this answer helpful?